# Stuck at starting gradle daemon

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, daemon

I am an Android Developer.
Yesterday I opened my current project at Android Studio 
and the project could not start.

An error was shown:

```
Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
        This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
        For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
        Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
        Please read the following process output to find out more:
        -----------------------
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (4s 245ms)
```

- I already edited `graddle.properties` to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m` but its still not work
- I already reinstalled my android studio with its gradle but this bug still persists
- I already deleted `.gradle` folder on my computer but its still stuck
- I already set build process heap size in Android studio but it still not work
- I already checked my antivirus and my firewall (even turn it off) but nothing happens

I need help here, because I can't run my project at all.

Here is the gradle log:

```
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at
https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
```

and this is log from daemon log

```
20:37:16.805 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
20:37:16.805 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
20:37:16.806 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
20:37:16.808 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
20:37:16.808 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000
20:37:16.814 [ERROR] [system.err] 
20:37:16.814 [ERROR] [system.err] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
20:37:16.815 [ERROR] [system.err] 
20:37:16.815 [ERROR] [system.err] * What went wrong:
20:37:16.815 [ERROR] [system.err] java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
20:37:16.815 [ERROR] [system.err] 
20:37:16.815 [ERROR] [system.err] * Try:
20:37:16.815 [ERROR] [system.err] Run with --stacktrace option to get the
stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run
with --scan to get full insights.
20:37:16.816 [ERROR] [system.err] 
20:37:16.816 [ERROR] [system.err] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Daemon vm is shutting down... The daemon has exited normally or was
terminated in response to a user interrupt.
```

Comment: After a lot of strugle and confuse, I found an issue. It seems my windows update did something that make daemon stop its process. So Aftare trying to restore my windows to a precious state (about 2 days ago) it seems the process is came back to normal.

Comment: In the future, consider cross posting on the Gradle forums. They're very helpful there.

Comment: already tried that yesterday, but nobody response.. so I put the issue here

Answer (score 7):

I resolved this by turning off Hotspot on my pc. Found the solution [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/67033172684/)

Comment: Yeah this is my issue too, but why? But thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 2):

start your local VPN app (such as 1.1.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have something like this in any of your gradle files:

   ```
   jvmArgs('someValues')
   ```
2. Go to your project config:

[image]

Go to "edit configurations". Make sure you select "app".

[image]

Check the launch flags. Delete them all >:D

3. Clean and rebuild your project
4. You (or a program) probably changed the jvm's default run options.
   Try to change them in your JVM or reinstall java and jdk if you're desperate enough.

Let me know how it goes

Comment: well the gradle.properties put jvmARgs=Xmx1536m for default I already try to delete it, but stil failed...

and for your second method, because I reinstall Android Studio, its delete all configuration on my old project, And now it becomes empty (Because to generate configuration, the Android studio need to complete the gradle, and I am stuck at starting daemon graddle )

Answer (score 0):

Go into your home directory and find the `.gradle` folder. Under that folder, there are 2 folder that I delete to remove this issue. I delete the `.gradle/daemons` and the `.gradle/caches` directory. Once I deleted those 2 directories and restarted Intellij/Android Studio, gradle sync started working.

On mac/linux

```
cd ~/.gradle
rm -fr caches daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following thing

1. Turn off pc hotspot
2. Restart your system
3. Invalidate cache and restart pc